# You don't have authorization to view this page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am working on creating one login page in which I am actually taking my user roles and authorities.

When I am running my application after creating it, it ran successfully and data has been saved and retrieved to & from the database. The flow of login page was working fine. Now when I stopped my application and ran it again it started throwing error as `Access to localhost was denied You don't have authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403`

I have three tables present called **roles**, **users** & **users_roles**, The data in my tables are present as my application was running fine on the first run so *users* has below data present inside it
+----+-----------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | email           | name       | password                                                     |
+----+-----------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | test@test.com   | Test Test  | $2a$10$wZmECBgChtCTbirlKvzWheNNulqJrbCQY925tVgKL3h3q0aDAqYwe |
|  2 | imran@vinbox.in | Imran Khan | $2a$10$4yow6JhDHeOHC9SiYE/MIOA6zl6jB6o6EOvw2gB7eWHJ/gru33TIa |
+----+-----------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+

The *roles* table
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | ROLE_ADMIN |
The *users_roles* table
+---------+---------+
| user_id | role_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       3 |       1 |
+---------+---------+

The application ran successfully when I ran it for the first time, The code for my **SpringSecurity.java**

```
package com.example.registrationlogindemo.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SpringSecurity {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/users").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                ).formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/users")
                                .permitAll()
                ).logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

**roles.java** consists of

```
package com.example.registrationlogindemo.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

**User.java** consists of

```
package com.example.registrationlogindemo.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="users_roles",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

After enabling the ** Call Stack ** or Security logs as debug I got stack as

```
Call stack: 

    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.Logger.info(Logger.java:46)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter$DebugRequestWrapper.getSession(DebugFilter.java:171)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleAccessDeniedException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I tried changing it to the **.anyRequest().authenticated()** but it does not work out for me. I digged every possible debugging from my side but not able to find it, help would be appreciated.

The userServiceImpl.java is below

```
package com.example.registrationlogindemo.service.impl;

import com.example.registrationlogindemo.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.registrationlogindemo.entity.Role;
import com.example.registrationlogindemo.entity.User;
import com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.registrationlogindemo.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository,
                           RoleRepository roleRepository,
                           PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userDto.getFirstName() + " " + userDto.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());

        //encrypt the password once we integrate spring security
        //user.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        if(role == null){
            role = checkRoleExist();
        }
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(role));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserDto> findAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users.stream().map((user) -> convertEntityToDto(user))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private UserDto convertEntityToDto(User user){
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        String[] name = user.getName().split(" ");
        userDto.setFirstName(name[0]);
        userDto.setLastName(name[1]);
        userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        return userDto;
    }

    private Role checkRoleExist() {
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }
}
```

I already tried changing the **roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");** as **roleRepository.findByName("ADMIN");** but it wont created any affect.

Please help me wit the possible solution for the same!